# net.objecthunter.exp4j.Expression equivalent in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there is equivalent in C# to JAVA net.objecthunter.exp4j.Expression;

I am trying to translate this JAVA function function:

```
    Expression expression;
    String[] variables;

    public WB_ExpressionScalarParameter(String equation, params String[] vars)
    {
        ExpressionBuilder expressionBuilder = new ExpressionBuilder(equation);
        variables = new String[vars.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < vars.Length; i++)
        {
            expressionBuilder.variable(vars[i]);
            variables[i] = vars[i];
        }
        try
        {
            expression = expressionBuilder.build();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception( "Can't parse equation. Please check equation and parameters.");
        }
    }
```

and the Expresion type is referenced from:
import net.objecthunter.exp4j.Expression;
import net.objecthunter.exp4j.ExpressionBuilder;

What this function does: it takes a string and convert to expression. If there is such a type in .NET as Expression?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [matheval](https://github.com/matheval/expression-evaluator-c-sharp) which has a lot of similarity with exp4j.